# How to change background color in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any what I could change the background color with javascript? For example:

```
<div id="factboxes">
        <div id="counter">
           <div class="factbox">
                <div class="counter-value "><?php echo end($total); ?></div>
                <p>Total Number Of Human Count</p>
          </div>
          
           <div class="factbox factboxgap">
                <div class="counter-value "><?php echo end($current); ?></div>
                <p>Current Number Of Human Count</p>
           </div>
           
           <div class="factbox factboxgap">
                <div class="counter-value "><?php echo count($reserve); ?> </div>
                <p>Total Number of Reservation</p>
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        if (<?php $total?> < 85){
            document.div.factbox.backgroundColor = "green";
        }
    </script>
```

If the total is less than 85 then the background color will be green. I tried to code in this way but nothing happen. I'm still new with javascript, hope someone could help me and explain how should it be done. Thank you

Comment: You need to `echo $total;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div id="factboxes">
    <div id="counter">
       <div class="factbox" id="TotalDiv">
            <div class="counter-value "><?php echo end($total); ?></div>
            <p>Total Number Of Human Count</p>
      </div>
      
       <div class="factbox factboxgap">
            <div class="counter-value "><?php echo end($current); ?></div>
            <p>Current Number Of Human Count</p>
       </div>
       
       <div class="factbox factboxgap">
            <div class="counter-value "><?php echo count($reserve); ?> </div>
            <p>Total Number of Reservation</p>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    if (<?php echo $total; ?> < 85){
        document.getElementById("TotalDiv").style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }
</script>
```

EDIT: fixed typo in javascript

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.body.style.backgroundColor` to change the color.

Read more about it on W3SChools: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundcolor.asp

Answer (score 0):

since you have already assigned class name as `factbox`, you can simply use this code:

`document.getElementsByClassName("factbox")[0].style.backgroundColor = "green"`

The `[0]` is to select the 1st element from the returned array.